# Javascript calls in wordpress for Stripe button

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if the donation button on my blog is working fine. I want to track button clicked and donation complete (otherwise I'm losing money). I use mixpanel to do that. But for some strange reason I'm getting something wrong; I have no record of the event. Here is the code I put AFTER THE `<BODY>` TAG on every page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$('#simpay-payment-btn stripe-button-el').click(function(){
    mixpanel.track(“Donate Started“);
});
</script>
```

Comment: https://help.mixpanel.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000865566-Set-up-Your-Tracking

Comment: That's a syntax error. Use `"` around your strings, not `“`.

Comment: If this script is directly into the body before the element it targets (wirth `id="simpay-payment-btn stripe-button-el"`, it runs before the element exists. Put it at the end of the body, just before the end tag, or wrap it in an onload handler.

Comment: Sorry it's not working. I don't know what's wrong really. Seemed normal.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it working
Don't forget to check the existence of the button!

```
if(document.getElementById('donate')){
    document.getElementById("donate").onclick = function() {
        mixpanel.track("Donated");
    };
}
```